# Should I use mysqli_set_charset every time I set up a connection?

Tags: php, mysqli, character-encoding

The encoding settings of the database and of the PHP client must match. When they do not, question marks appear instead of legitimate non-ascii text as in *B?r* instead of *Bär*.

When I create a database I use

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

When I open a connection in my PHP scripts (omitting the required checks for error conditions), I write

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,mydatabase);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8')
```

On some servers dropping `mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8')` causes question marks to appear. On these servers `mysqli_character_set_name($conn)` returns encodings other than `utf8`.

Can I reliably set up Apache and Nginx to ensure that PHP client always uses UTF8 when connecting to MariaDB/MySQL (that is `mysqli_character_set_name()` always return `utf8`), or should I always follow `mysqli_connect()` with `mysqli_set_charset()` if I want to use non-ascii text data?

Comment: You can encode your files to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use mysqli_set_charset every time I set up a connection?

Yes.
It has nothing to do with Apache or PHP in general, but with a "language" PHP speaks with mysql in particular. And to negotiate which "language" have to be used, the `mysqli_set_charset()` function is for.

Comment: But wouldn't asking the DBA to set `init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'`  do any harm either?